Doubts in interpreting 2 way interaction lme
I have some doubts in interpreting my data. So, if I have this model m1 <- lme(speed ~ car_type + car_store + car_type:car_store,  data = data1, random = ~ 1 | car_owner, method = "ML")
car type : 'A', 'B', 'C' 
car store : 'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF'

The model showed an interaction between car type and car store. For instance, the interaction  cartypeC:caarstoreBCD had a positive estimated value (.250).
I interpreted this as car type C having a higher value than car type A in car store BCD compared to car store ABC. However, when I checked the mean values, car type C
store BCD had a mean of -5, while car type A
store ABC had a mean of -1. Due to these, I don't understand why the estimation for the interaction is positive. Any advice ? Thanks

You can find this answered by searching our site.
